# Create a file with maven

Tags: python, maven

I am using maven to generate some protobuf python code but it erases the **init**.py every time.

I was wondering if maven had a tool to create a blank **init**.py so that I do not need to create it manually every single time.

(Maybe a copy from a different **init**.py)

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.xolstice.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>protobuf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.5.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <checkStaleness>true</checkStaleness>
                    <staleMillis>10000</staleMillis>
                    <protocExecutable>${protocLocation}</protocExecutable>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile protobuf</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                            <goal>test-compile-python</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile-python</id>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile-python</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <checkStaleness>false</checkStaleness>
                            <outputDirectory>${pythonOutputDirectory}</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

This is the plugin that generates the code and removes the **init**.py

Note that I set checkstaleness to false.   This means it will write protobuf files even if they are not older than a certain time.  This is because it was not detecting changes and not writing them out.

EDIT:

The solution was found here:
https://github.com/xolstice/protobuf-maven-plugin/issues/9

Instead of creating a new file.  I instead just didn't delete it.
(for anyone else wanting to create a file through maven... keep searching!)

Comment: where is the `init.py` located in your maven project? how do you generate code? using which maven plugin?

Comment: the protobuf plugin it blasts the directory where it writes the files so all files in that directory dissapear

Answer (score 0):

The solution was found here:
https://github.com/xolstice/protobuf-maven-plugin/issues/9

Instead of creating a new file.  I instead just didn't delete it.
(for anyone else wanting to create a file through maven... keep searching!)

Comment: Maven Antrun plugin can create files via ant. There's probably a groovy plugin and a jython plugin too.